# Python number guessing game - Cannot display a win

Tags: python

I'm still quite new to Python so I apologise if this is too easy or stupid, but I was recently given the task to create a number guessing game. The game has 100 numbers, numbered from 1 to 100, and will also have a dice roll numbered 1 to 6 to determine how many tries you get (e.g If the user rolls a 4, the user will get 4 turns to try and guess the number between 1 to 100).  So far I managed to complete most of it, however, upon testing the program myself, when I actually get the correct answer it doesn't display a win.

```
import random

random_number = random.randint(1, 5)#I made the range from 1 to 5 to make my chances of guessing the correct number greater#
guessnum_dice = random.randint(1, 6)
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = guessnum_dice
out_of_guesses = False
win = False

# This name function prints out the users name; this is because the task asks me to save each game's
# statisitics and record them within an external text file. Still haven't figured out how to do that
# as well :(
def name_function():
    x = input("Enter your name: ")
    print("Hello, " + x)
    return
name_function()



user_roll = input("Type \"roll\" to roll the dice: ")
if user_roll == "roll":
    print("You have "+str(guessnum_dice) + " guesses. Use them wisely!")



if guessnum_dice == 1:
    user_guess = input("Guess the secret number: ")
    if user_guess != random_number:
        out_of_guesses = True

if guessnum_dice == 2:
    while guess_count < guess_limit:
        user_guess = input("Guess the secret number: ")
        guess_count += 1
        if user_guess < str(random_number):
            print("Higher!")
        elif user_guess > str(random_number):
            print("Lower")
       #Here Ive tried making the user's guess equal to the number, but to no success
         elif user_guess == random_number:
            win = True
            print("You Win")
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True


if guessnum_dice == 3:
    while guess_count < guess_limit:
        user_guess = input("Guess the secret number: ")
        guess_count += 1
        if user_guess < str(random_number):
            print("Higher!")
        elif user_guess > str(random_number):
            print("Lower")
        elif user_guess == random_number:
            win = True
            print("You Win")
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True


if guessnum_dice == 4:
    while guess_count < guess_limit:
        user_guess = input("Guess the secret number: ")
        guess_count += 1
        if user_guess < str(random_number):
            print("Higher!")
        elif user_guess > str(random_number):
            print("Lower")
        elif user_guess == random_number:
            win = True
            print("You Win")
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True


if guessnum_dice == 5:
    while guess_count < guess_limit:
        user_guess = input("Guess the secret number: ")
        guess_count += 1
        if user_guess < str(random_number):
            print("Higher!")
        elif user_guess > str(random_number):
            print("Lower")
        elif user_guess == random_number:
            win = True
            print("You Win")
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True


if guessnum_dice == 6:
    while guess_count < guess_limit:
        user_guess = input("Guess the secret number: ")
        guess_count += 1
        if user_guess < str(random_number):
            print("Higher!")
        elif user_guess > str(random_number):
            print("Lower")
        elif user_guess == random_number:
            win = True
            print("You Win")
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True




if out_of_guesses:
    print("You Lose! The number: " + str(random_number))

if win == True:
    print("You won")
```

And here is the output:

```
Enter your name: Gary
Hello, Gary
Type "roll" to roll the dice: roll
You have 6 guesses. Use them wisely!
Guess the secret number: 4
Lower
Guess the secret number: 3
Lower
Guess the secret number: 2  ### Here you can see that 2 is the correct answer, but it wont display a- 
Guess the secret number: 2  ### -win no matter how many times it gets entered
Guess the secret number: 2
Guess the secret number: 1
Higher!
You Lose! The number: 2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Once again I apoligise if this seems confusing as I find it difficult to try and explain my problem. Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: Not directly related to your issue, but you have several code blocks beginning `if guessnum_dice == ...`.  How do those code blocks differ from one another / can you think of a way to consolidate some of this logic?

Comment: You are comparing strings to strings as though they are integers. This does not work like expected in Python. Compare `int` to `int` instead.

Comment: Another side note: Is it possible to be both out of guesses and to have won?  Or are these 2 mutually exclusive end states?  Is there a way you could amend your code based on that?

Comment: And you can simply use a `for` loop to loop for each dice roll outcome, you don't need those complex `if` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using loop to go through all guesses instead of using if statements, in this way your code will be more compact and you can change the loop counter as you wish.

Also when you get user input, cast it to integer so that you can compare the numbers, otherwise user input will remain as string. check out below solution:

```
#This is a guess the number game
import random

print("What is your name?")
myName = input()
print("Well, " + myName + ", I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20")

loopCounter = 0
myNumber = random.randint(1, 20)

while loopCounter < 6:
    print("Take a guess.")
    guessNumber = input()
    guessNumber = int(guessNumber)
    loopCounter = loopCounter + 1

    if guessNumber < myNumber:
        print("Your guess is too low.")
    elif guessNumber > myNumber:
        print("Your guess is too high.")
    else:
        loopCounter = str(loopCounter)
        print("Well done, " + myName + ", you guessed the number in " + loopCounter + " guesses!")
        break

if guessNumber != myNumber:
    myNumber = str(myNumber)
    print("Nope. The number was " + myNumber)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that helped quite a lot. I managed to add a 'roll the dice' variable to your loopCounter variable so the number can be between 1 to 6. Adding all those If statements before was so confusing, so this should really help.

Comment: you are welcome, I am glad that i could help. please allow me to give you a suggestion that helped me when i started. to improve your code style very quickly, you may find some tutorials about sort, search algorithms, and data structures. you will understand time and space complexity, how to optimize a piece of code etc. this will be great start